# What is "python" in the list of interpreter paths in Visual Studio Code? And can I remove it?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have been using python on Visual Studio Code for a while now, and today I noticed an extra path option when selecting an interpreter path that I haven't seen previously.

[image: Screenshot]

The path simply says "python" and if I try to select it, it selects (or reverts?) to the global/recommended path.

Why does this exist? Is there a way to remove it from the interpreter selection menu?

### Additional Information:

The python option also shows up in the command palette option `Filter Jupyter Kernel`, where still no path is given.
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Did you recently create a command alias named python?

Comment: You seem to be on Windows, and I don't use Windows, so I can't reliably reproduce your case, but VS Code looks for python interpreters in a lot of different places: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_where-the-extension-looks-for-environments. You may want to check if a `python` was set there.

Comment: @JohnGordon not that I know of, on cmd all I have is `conda="C:\Users\...\conda.bat"`, and on powershell there's nothing that resembles python. Any other places I should check?

Comment: @GinoMempin Would I be looking for a `python.exe` file or a `python` (no extension) file?  I checked the recommended locations but couldn't find anything. Also made an edit to the post, may or may not be helpful. (sorry if the ping was unnecessary, somewhat new to stackexchange)

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem in my vscode. This may be a hidden setting or a bug. I opened an [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/19651) in GitHub.

Comment: @Zander According to the comment in issue, please  provide the logs as mentioned in the issue template.

Answer (score 0):

A good news is Python team will release a new feature soon, which allows you to refresh and reselect your interpreter paths. Please keep an eye on the upcoming blog in September.